# Check if a function is callable

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, metaprogramming, enable-if

I am using the `is_callable` structure defined as follows

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_callable {
  template <typename U>
  static auto test(U* p) -> decltype((*p)(std::declval<Args>()...), void(), std::true_type());

  template <typename U>
  static auto test(...) -> decltype(std::false_type());

  static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<F>(nullptr))::value;
};
```

I am using this to test a lambda declared as:

```
template <typename T>
struct runner {
  T t;

  template <typename F, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_callable<F, T&>::value || is_callable<F, T&&>::value>::type>
  void run(F&& f) { 
    return f(t); 
  }
};

runner<int> a{0};
a.run([&] (auto& x) {
  x++;
});
```

Why does this fail compilation on the `enable_if` on AppleClang? Shouldn't the `auto`s get deduced correctly?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83c21fddc4e15cb). What is your `clang` version and what is the specific error message?

Comment: @Rakete1111 `candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if'`
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)

Comment: Why are you checking if it's callable with `T&` *or* `T&&`? You're calling it with `T&`, just check that.

Comment: Why do you put decltype around false_type()? Your function can just return false_type. Also, why the void() in the other test?  You probably want the nullptr of type F*. Finally, your user of enable_if it's wrong. Since generic lambdas require C++14, might as well use the easier enable_if_t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case for the `true_type` `test` looks wrong.  At any rate, your code is more complicated than it needs to be.  Try the following minimal working example:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename...Args> struct is_callable {
  template<typename F2, typename...Args2> static constexpr std::true_type
  test(decltype(std::declval<F2>()(std::declval<Args2>()...)) *) { return {}; }

  template<typename F2, typename...Args2> static constexpr std::false_type
  test(...) { return {}; }

  static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<F, Args...>(nullptr))::value;
};

void f0();
static_assert(is_callable<decltype(f0)>::value, "f0()");
static_assert(!is_callable<decltype(f0), int>::value, "f0(0)");

int f1(int);
static_assert(!is_callable<decltype(f1)>::value, "f1()");
static_assert(is_callable<decltype(f1), int>::value, "f1(0)");
static_assert(!is_callable<decltype(f1), int, int>::value, "f1(0, 0)");

auto __attribute__((unused)) f2 = [](int, char *) { return 7; };
static_assert(is_callable<decltype(f2), int, char *>::value, "f2(int, char *)");
static_assert(!is_callable<decltype(f2), int, int>::value, "f2(int, int)");
```

Comment: That's a *horrible* `is_callable`.

Comment: What's horrible? It works with C++ 11, 14, and 17, and uses SFINAE  very explicitly and clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `is_callable` test class, but your usage of it.

When using `std::enable_if` in the template argument list of a **function**, you have to use it this way:

```
template <typename T>
struct runner {
  T t;

  template 
  <
  typename F, 
  std::enable_if_t<is_callable<std::decay_t<F>, T&>::value || is_callable<F, T&&>::value>* = nullptr
  >
  void run(F&& f) { 
    return f(t); 
  }
};
```

The form you have tried to use is for use as a trailing return type:

```
  template<typename F>
  auto run(F&& f) 
  -> std::enable_if_t<is_callable<std::decay_t<F>, T&>::value || is_callable<F, T&&>::value>
  { 
    return f(t); 
  }
```

The `is_callable` type is correct. It looks like one I have posted to stack overflow before.

Comment: Why do you think you *have* to use it that way?

Comment: @Barry because it's one of the 3 correct ways for enabling a function: type* = nullptr, trailing type or false argument.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that is the case. `template <..., typename = std::enable_if_t<...>>` is fairly commonly used.

Comment: @Barry to enable classes,  not functions.

Comment: The only case a default template argument doesn't work is when you need to apply SFINAE to multiple otherwise-identical overloads, as it is not part of the signature. That doesn't apply to OP's code.

Comment: @T.C. apple clang begs to differ. Perhaps a bug?